# How do I simulate relative rotations about dynamic vertices of a n-sided polygon in Geogebra?

Tags: rotational-matrices, geogebra, transformation-matrix

I'm trying to replicate the following geogebra simulation for an n-sided polygon.
[Simulation Sample](https://www.geogebra.org/m/rmfmgbqp)
At the moment the simulation is hard coded meaning that the vertices of the pentagon are individually rotated about the respective points.

This is a problem because I'm trying to do the same for n-sided polygon, where the user has the ability to change n. Since the points about which each triangle is rotated are dynamic and dependent on the rotation of the previous triangle, how do I go about doing this?

I feel like I need a transformation matrix, but feels like it 's complicated. How should I think about this? Does it actually need to be hard-coded?

This is the exact simulation I'm looking to replicate.[Simulation Sample 2](https://www.geogebra.org/m/gvauh2qS)
Even here every rotation has been hard coded to exhaust all possibilities for n. They have hard coded the rotation for 8 vertices, which is the max for n.

I have tried various methods but I've found that without predefined points about which the relative rotations have to be made, the rotations don't work out. And I can't predefine these points, because they are dynamic, and rotating themselves.

Comment: As far as I can see, the only thing that's hard coded in Simulation Sample 2 is the maximum number of points, in the sense that there are a lot of points defined by indexing into the various lists with specific integer indices, and these indices only go up to 9 (one more than the greatest number of sides allowed). If you simply add more points using higher indices, you can then let the number of sides go higher and it all works -- all of the transformations are computed dynamically. But I am not familiar enough with Geogebra list processing to know if you could just keep everything as lists..

Comment: You might also look at the Spreadsheet view of Geogebra, I have found it handy when dealing with large quantities of entities.